# Complexity of if statement inside or outside for loop

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Let's compare this:

```py
for path in filePaths :
    if(self.module!=organizer and self.module!=decoder):
        # some code with loops
    elif(self.module==decoder):
        # some code with loops
```

and this:

```py
if(self.module!=organizer and self.module!=decoder):
    for path in filePaths :
        # some code with loops
elif(self.module==decoder):
    for path in filePaths :
        # some code with loops
```

Which one is the most efficient and why?

Comment: The question title says time complexity, but the question text says efficiency, which is a bit different. For the sake of completeness, these two pieces of code have the same time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both have an O(n) complexity, but the latter is more efficient. Since `self.module` doesn't change during the execution of the loop, there's no point in checking it in each iteration.

Comment: unless `self.module` *does* change in the missing code

Comment: @Chris_Rands if the missing code can modify `self.module`, these two snippets are not equivalent. In that case, it isn't a question of performance - (at least) one of them is wrong, and should not be used.

Comment: yeah self.module doesn't change, thanks for your answer i was thinking the same but was not sure !

Comment: Correct answer based on the information given, but it potentially depends on what `some code with loops` does.